# Mailchimp Repeatable not working using Mandrill

Tags: php, mailchimp, mandrill

I am sending the repeatable content to the mandrill template which tied up with mailchimp through API using "weblee/mandrill" in laravel(php).

Content format sending to the API

```
$this->data['products'][]['title'] = "title1";
$this->data['products'][]['title'] = "title2";
$this->data['products'][]['title'] = "title3";
$this->data['products'][]['title'] = "title4";
$this->data['products'][]['title'] = "title5";
$this->data['name'] = 'John';
sendMandrilTemplate(template-name,'Subject','abc@gmail.com',$this->data);



public static function sendMandrilTemplate($template_name,$subject,$to,$data){
        $mandril = new Mail(env('MANDRILL_SECRET'));
        $message = array(
                'subject' => $subject,
                'from_email' => config('mail.from')['address'],
                'to' => array(array('email' => $to)),
                'merge_vars' => array(array(
                    'rcpt' => $to,
                  )));
        $i = 0;
        foreach($data as $key => $value){
            $template_content[$i]['name']= $key;
            $template_content[$i]['content'] = $value;
            $i++;
        }
        $result = $mandril->messages()->sendTemplate($template_name,$template_content,$message);

        return $result;
    }
```

In mandrill template I am calling this data as following

```
    Hi <span mc:edit="name"></span>,    
    Products title list is as follows:
    <table>
      <tr><th> Product List </th></tr>
      <tr mc:repeatable="products">  
         <td><span mc:edit="title"></span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

In email, I am not receiving the email content for repeatable products title, remaining is working fine including recipient name. Please guide, what I am missing in it.

Answer (score 0):

According to:
[Mandrill Zendesk](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582497-Using-Editable-Content-Areas-in-Templates)

Other aspects of the MailChimp template language won't be recognized in Mandrill, so if you've created a template for use in MailChimp, it may need a bit of tweaking to allow editable regions to be replaced by Mandrill. **For example, repeatable areas in MailChimp templates can't be repeated via Mandrill so you'd instead want to add multiple mc:edit regions for the number of items or sections you want to include.**

which is pretty terrible tstl =(

Comment: if your repeatable is very simple, maybe you just construct the entire html serverside and send it as 1 html_str variable.   if it's complex but you only have very few repeats, then maybe just use their IF/ELSE/END logic to test for the exact number of block you need.